# Do all general measures on $\mathbb{R}$ look like this?

Tags: real-analysis

Where given subset E,

$\mu (E) = \int_E f$

for a function f on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be describing measures absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure (assuming the integral is supposed to be with respect to Lebesgue measure).  The simplest measures not of this form are point masses, for example the Dirac measure where a set has measure $1$ if it contains $0$ and has measure $0$ otherwise.  But there are lots of more complicated measures not of the indicated form, for example, measures that concentrate on the Cantor set.

Comment: Ok I understand thank you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#The_assumption_of_.CF.83-finiteness